# Can I get the screenshots of the assembly codes?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

I know this is outside the scope of the community but I had nowhere else to turn to. I need screenshots of Visual Studio after running the following programs for an assignment. My PC died and it is due in a few hours. There are two MASM programs and they are both interactive, any logical variables will do. You can send the link of the images to:mihijek116@vapaka.com (attachments will not work) if the question is closed. Thanks in advance

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

 .data
fname BYTE 16 Dup(?)
age dword  ?
np BYTE 'Enter Name:',0dh, 0ah,0
ap BYTE 'Enter Age:',0dh, 0ah,0
yn BYTE 'Your name is ',0
yy BYTE ' born in ',0
cy dword 2022
 dob dword ?
.code
main PROC
mov edx, offset np
call WriteString

mov edx, offset fn
mov ecx, Sizeof fn
call readstring

call Crlf
mov edx, offset ap
call WriteString

call readInt
mov  age, eax

mov eax, cy
sub eax, age
mov yob, eax

mov edx, offset yn
call WriteString

mov edx, offset fn
call WriteString

mov edx, offset yy
 call WriteString

mov eax, dob
call WriteDec

call Crlf


call WaitMsg

 exit
main ENDP
 END main












INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
two dword 2 ; store two
three dword 3 ; store three
c dword 1 ; store 1
n dword  ? ; n variable
answer dword  ? ; answer variable
a1 dword ? ; store 2n^2
a2 dword ? ; store 3n
pr BYTE 'Enter n:',0dh, 0ah,0     ; n prompt
eq BYTE 'ans= ',0 ; ans

.code

n2n PROC ; 2*n*n
mov eax, two
mov ecx, n
mul ecx
mov ecx,n
mul ecx
mov a1,eax
ret
n2n ENDP

n3 PROC   ; 3n
mov eax, three
mov ecx, n
mul ecx
mov a2,eax
ret
3n ENDP

main PROC
mov edx, offset pr
call WriteString ; Ask user for n

call readInt
mov  n, eax ; Store user input in n

call n2n ; call procedure n2n
call 3n ; call procedure n3

mov ebx, a1
add ebx, a2
add ebx, c
mov answer, ebx ; store result in answer

mov edx, offset eq
call WriteString

mov eax, answer
call WriteDec
call WaitMsg

 exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a real question, intentionally off-topic.  If someone's feeling generous and have an Irvine32 env set up, they might want to run this code and link a screenshot somewhere regardless of this being closed, although IDK why that would be necessary for submitting homework vs. just the code.

Comment: @marcherder they don't even compile :/ some variable names unknown, some (looks like) typos

Comment: You might be able to use an online IDE with MASM + Irvine32.  Google found https://onecompiler.com/assembly/3vr9ex3fk .  Or maybe not that one, trying to run it just gives syntax errors so probably it's not MASM at all, probably NASM for Linux given the mention of `_start`.  And google just found someone's failed attempt to try an Irvine32 program there.